# IntelliJ how do I generate a new class?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-14

When I go to my project structure and right click -> new, I only see new file/folder etc... but no class generation or packages. How do I get IntelliJ to do this? (I have Intellij 14 Ultimate - see image below)

[image: intellij]

Comment: Do you right-click on a folder that is one of the source roots ot test source roots folder of the project?

Comment: Added a screenshot @BranislavLazic.

Comment: @JBNizet see screenshot, think i'm doing it correctly as this is how it worked in RubyMines

Comment: Given the color of the folder, it's not a sources root folder. Read Bohuslav Burghardt's answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

IntelliJ will offer the option to create new class in the new menu, only if you right click within the part of your project structure, which is marked as Sources root or Test sources root.

In your case, right click the `src/main` directory in the project structure view and select *Mark directory As/Sources Root*. That should fix it.

---

Also, Gradle expects Java classes to be placed in `src/main/java` (and test Java classes in `src/test/java`) by default. I think that if you followed this convention, IntelliJ would mark those folders as (Test) Sources Root automatically. So maybe it would be better solution to adjust your project structure according to this convention.

Here is a quote from [Gradle guide](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_java_projects.html) regarding this issue:

> Gradle expects to find your production source code under src/main/java
>   and your test source code under src/test/java

Comment: Awesome that worked, can't tick it yet as you were too quick! Will do it in a few minutes :)